# I need to save an entity, which is related to another entity that has 2 foreign keys on NESTusing TypeORM

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, nestjs-typeorm

I'm going to simplify this, I have 3 entities.

```
//1er entity
@Entity()
export class Song{

@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
SongId: string;

@Column()//this is a UserId
Owner: string;

@OneToMany( type => Lyric, lyric => lyric.Song, {
cascade: true
})//I supposed different versions
Lyrics: Lyric[];
}
```

```
//2nd entity
@Entity()
export class Usuario {

@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
UsuarioId: string;

@ManyToMany(type => Song, song => Song.songId)
@JoinTable()
Songs: Song[] | null;

@OneToMany( type => Lyric, lyric => lyric.User)
Lyrics: Lyric[] | null;
```

```
//3er entity
@Entity()
export class Lyric{
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
LyricId: string;

@Colum()
lyric: string;    

@ManyToOne( type => User, user => user.Lyrics)
User: User;

@ManyToOne( type => Song, song => song.Lyrics)
Song: Song;
}
```

So I have my user created, no songs or lyrics, but I have his id

```
user = {
UserId = '0433bd30-e21d-4581-8906-a5ee1a5b23d4',
Songs = [],
Lyrics = []
}
```

When I am creating a song I need my UserId and my lyric or lyrics

```
const song= this.repository.create({
userId,
Lyrics
})
```

I was trying this on my Lyrics

```
Lyrics = [
{
UserId: userId,
Lyric: 'hello, hello, this is the lyric, etc etc'
},
{
UserId: userId,
Lyric: 'hello again, hello, this is the lyric, etc etc'
},
]
```

So i try to save my song

```
await this.repository.save(cancion)
```

All it's ok, but my Lyric entity only get the SongId and UserId is empty

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqt6X.png)

So what Im doing righ now is make two saves, but idw if I can get this doing only one

That's what Im doing right now

```
Lyrics.forEach(async lyric=> {
const newLyricWithUserAndSong : CreateLyricDto = {
SongId: song.songId,// this is my first save await this.repository.save(song)
...lytic
}

await this.lyricService.create(newLyricWithUserAndSong )
```

I think there is a bad configuration with the entities, when I save a song everything works correctly, but my lyrics entity only takes SongId and UserId is empty

What do u think about it?

Answer (score 0):

**Part #1**

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
SongId: string;
```

and

```
@ManyToMany(type => Song, song => Song.songId)
@JoinTable()
Songs: Song[] | null;
```

There is no property `songId` on `Song`. There is a property `SongId`.

---

**Part #2**

Check better this part:

```
const newLyricWithUserAndSong : CreateLyricDto = {
SongId: song.songId,// this is my first save await this.repository.save(song)
...lyric
}
```

If `lyric` comes with empty/undefined `SongId`, it will get overwritten, because it comes *after* `SongId`. Besides `SongId` and `songId` are different props.

---

**Part #3**

What's the use of defining reverse relationship to `Lyrics` on `User`? Leave `user` on `Lyrics` only, and you'll still be able to fetch lyrics for given user. And there will be one entity to save. Similarly, only `Lyrics` need relation to `Song`. `Song` doesn't need to have reverse relation with lyrics.
If I'm getting your struggle well, that should save you a loooooot of hassle. You'll only update `Lyrics`, and still be able to fetch lyrics for song, songs for one lyrics, user for lyrics, and lyrics for user.

Besides, that's what TypeORM does, I guess?

---

**Part #4**

Switch to MikroORM :D